# My simple custom shortcode is not longer working (possibly due to upgrade to WordPress 4.4 ?)

Tags: functions, shortcode, line-breaks

I have a simple function in functions.php that creates a custom shortcode:

```
function my_line_break() {
    return "<br>";
}
add_shortcode( 'new line', 'my_line_break' );
```

Now, I don't know if this happened after upgrading to 4.4 but it's not longer working and pages just render `[new line]` in plain text.

Anyone can help with this?
I looked at https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/23/changes-to-the-shortcode-api/ but I'm not sure it relates?

P.S. I know this wouldn't be the right way to handle line breaks, but I did it as a way to make life simpler for my customer (so as a little side question, if there is a valid and simple to use alternative, could you please let me know it so I can also bypass this problem completely?).

Comment: Please try to rename your shortcode to 'new_line' - maybe the space breaks it.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I wonder if this is related to changes to the API that I linked. Anyway, please post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the comment to an answer,

please rename your Shortcode to not contain spaces (`new_line`):

```
function my_line_break() {
    return "<br>";
}
add_shortcode( 'new_line', 'my_line_break' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shortcode name is incorrect . [Shortcode API - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Names)

So you can write like :

```
function my_line_break() {
    return "<br>";
}
add_shortcode( 'newline', 'my_line_break' );
```

Then :

```
[newline]
```